# How can I make a program that can covert from speech to text to use with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, speech-to-text

As the title, I want to make a program that could convert from speech to text to work with an Arduino equipment. Can someone tutorial me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before you ask a question, there is an expectation that you show some effort to solve a specific problem. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing or resource discovery service.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino is very slow, you can not recognize speech on it. You need more powerful CPU, at least RPI.